# Изменение цвета фона в консоли python(RGB)

Tags: python, консоль, rgb

Возможно ли сделать так что-бы при запуске кода python, фон консоли были изменён на любой цвет. Например `rgb(250, 250, 250)`?

Comment: В целом - нет. Если нужен любой RGB цвет - создавайте "нормальное" окно, и рисуйте в нем как хотите.

Comment: ANSI escape code подойдет? ```print(u"\u001b[34;5;7mHELLOWORLD")```